# How to write sub-component (child components) in es6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to refactor my react app from es5 to es6, however in render function I've kept my  and  components, when I refactor to ES6 these components are not displayed in my page. Searched in google but couldn't get the proper solution, below is my code

```js
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import Header from '../Header/header';
import Footer from '../Footer/footer';

export class Main extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <div>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

below is my Footer:

```js
'use strict';

import React from 'react';

export class Footer extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <footer>
                    <div className="panel panel-default">
                        <div className="panel-footer container">
                            &copy; {year} All rights reserved
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Header and Footer components are not being rendered.

Comment: have you imported it before?

Comment: Yes, I've imported

Comment: That code [works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/0pms6uqv/). Can you update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem? (Stack Snippets support React and JSX.)

Comment: It is not throwing any error, but I am not able to see Header and Footer components

Comment: looks like you're missing `default` to me

Comment: Your Stack Snippets aren't **runnable**. [Here's how to create a runnable ReactJS+JSX snippet.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-reactjs-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support) (Although in this case, you couldn't have used Stack Snippets, as the problem is the export/import.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either export your Header and Footer classes with **default** like this

```
export default class Footer
```

Or import it this way:

```
import {Footer} from '../pathToFile'
```

So there are two ways to export in ES6. The first one is a **default export** which is written like this:

```
export default someVariable
```

If you export a variable this way, the you can import it in any other file this way:

```
import someVariable from '<path>'
```

The catch here is that you can even import your variable with a different name. Hence,

```
import someVariable2 from '<path>'
```

will also give me someVariable. But there is a restriction as well. **You can have only one export default in a single file**

Now the other way of exporting is the **Named Export** like this:

```
export somevariable
```

In this case, you need to import it this way:

```
import {someVariable} from '<path>'
```

In this case, the variable name ca't be changed. You need to import it with the same name which you mentioned while exporting.